# AngularJS element directive with ng-init runs before view renders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to loop through an array and create multiple instances of a custom directive that creates different graphs based on some variables on the rootScope. Everything works fine except when I try to place those in a view and call ng-init to a method on the scope and pass it arguments.

What I am finding is that ng-init seems to run before anything (and I think ng-init is the wrong approach), which causes errors because the variables being set in the method aren't set yet when the ng-init runs in the view.

When I first load the index view, then go into this view, all is well, but when I try to load this view first or reload it, I am getting the errors. The ng-init is trying to call the chart() method before anything else runs.

On the index view, I have this chart in a modal that gets called onclick, so ng-init is not needed, therefore it works great.

I am a little stuck and what I need is advice on the "right" or better way to accomplish this.

On the detail view, I need to loop across that array to get four charts based on four different objects of data.

The data is a static file for now, as this is a prototype.

My code is essentially this: 
View:

```
<div id="chart_list">
  <div class="chart" ng-repeat="val in ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']" ng-init="chart('line', val, itemId, val)">
    <h3>{{val | uppercase}}</h3>
    <chart/>
  </div>
</div>
```

AppController method:

```
// get data set up for chart consumption
$scope.chart = function(chart, kpi, socId, chartId) {

$rootScope.visualize = {};
$rootScope.visualize.chart = chart;
$rootScope.visualize.chartId = chartId;
$rootScope.visualize.val = val;
$rootScope.visualize.item = $rootScope.itemList[itemId];
$rootScope.visualize.valName = $rootScope.visualize.item[val].name;
```

};

DetailView controller:

```
app.controller('ItemDetailController', function($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, ItemList) {

  var itemId = $scope.itemId = $routeParams.itemId;

  ItemList.get({}, function(res) {
    $rootScope.itemList = res.data;
    $scope.item = $rootScope.itemList[itemId];
  });


});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('ItemList', function($resource){
  return $resource("/api/item-list.json");
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('chart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

      if ($(window).width() <= 1200){
        var width = 300;
      } else {
        var width = 450;
      }

      var visualize = scope.visualize;
      var data = visualize.soc[visualize.val].data;
      var numTicks = Object.keys(data).length;

      element.append('<div class="chart_container"><div id="y_axis' + visualize.chartId +'" class="y_axis"></div><div id="chart' + visualize.chartId + '" class="chart"></div><div id="x_axis' + visualize.chartId + '" class="x_axis"></div></div>');
      element.append('<div id="legend_container' + visualize.chartId +'" class="legend_container"><div id="smoother' + visualize.chartId +'" title="Smoothing"></div><div id="legend' + visualize.chartId +'"></div></div>');

      var valSeries = [];
      var valSeries2 = [];
      var valSeries3 = [];
      var valMap = {};
      var i = 0;

      Object.keys(data).forEach(function(propertyName) {
        var value = data[propertyName];
        var val2 = (Math.random() * (102 - 87) + 86) / 100;
        var val3 = (Math.random() * (95 - 70) + 69) / 100;
        valSeries.push({x: i, y: data[propertyName].amount});
        valSeries2.push({x: i, y: data[propertyName].amount * val2});
        valSeries3.push({x: i, y: data[propertyName].amount * val3});
        valMap[i] = data[propertyName].name;
        i++;
      });

      var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
        element: document.querySelector('#chart' + visualize.chartId), 
        width: width, 
        height: 150,
        renderer: visualize.chart,
        stroke: true,
        series: [
          {
            data: valSeries3,
            color: '#F0AD4E',
            name: 'Three years ago',
          },
          {
            data: valSeries2,
            color: '#5BC0DE',
            name: 'Two years ago',
          },
          {
            data: valSeries,
            color: '#5CB85C',
            name: 'Past year'
          }
        ]
      });

      var format = function(n) {
        var map = valMap;
        return map[n];
      }

      var x_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
        graph: graph,
        width: width,
        orientation: 'bottom',
        element: document.getElementById('x_axis' + visualize.chartId),
        pixelsPerTick: width/numTicks,
        tickFormat: format
      });

      var y_axis = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y({
        graph: graph,
        orientation: 'left',
        tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
        element: document.getElementById('y_axis' + visualize.chartId),
      });

      graph.render();

      var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail({
        graph: graph,
        formatter: function(series, x, y) {
          var content = app.lib[visualize.dataFormat](parseInt(y)) + "<br>";
          return content;
        }
      });

      var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
        graph: graph,
        element: document.getElementById('legend' + visualize.chartId)

      } );

      var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( {
        graph: graph,
        legend: legend
      } );

    }
  };
});
```

**Edit:**
I fixed this by removing the chart method altogether and replacing ng-init with attributes. Something like this:

```
<chart data-attrone="somedata" data-attrtwo="some other data" />
```

Then the attrs are available in the directive with `attrs.attrone`, etc.

Attribute names must be lower-case.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Hi Jason, if you solved the issue yourself it is [recommended](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) you answer your own question to more effectively help others.

Comment: Thanks for linking to that page, I didn't know about that policy of asking/answering your own questions intentionally. I see this sometimes and they get down voted. Good to know it's OK to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the chart method altogether and replacing ng-init with attributes. Something like this:

```
<chart data-attrone="somedata" data-attrtwo="some other data" />
```

Then the attrs are available in the directive with `attrs.attrone`, etc.

Attribute names must be lower-case.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Very helpful! Just in case other Angular newbies stumble on this: $attrs is injected into the controller using dependency injection.